# How to dynamically modify a Dash app's HTML <head> to update opengraph meta tags depending on the content displayed on the page

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash, meta-tags

I would like my dash app to properly [unfurl](https://medium.com/slack-developer-blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-unfurling-but-were-afraid-to-ask-or-how-to-make-your-e64b4bb9254) in Slack based on what content it displays when the link is copied. This means that when someone shares a link to the app in Slack, it will not only show the link but an image, a title and a description as well. This information must be provided to Slack in the HTML's `<head>` through `meta` tags. What I'm trying to achieve is to update these meta tags based on user input. Here is a small example:

```py
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, callback, Output, Input
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

app = Dash(__name__)

server = app.server


def return_data_up():
    data = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "y": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
    return data


def return_data_down():
    data = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "y": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]})
    return data


app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(children="My First App with Data and a Graph"),
        dcc.RadioItems(
            options=[
                "Up!",
                "Down!",
            ],
            value="Up!",
            id="plot-up-or-down",
        ),
        dcc.Graph(figure={}, id="my_figure"),
    ]
)

@callback(
    Output(component_id="my_figure", component_property="figure"),
    Input(component_id="plot-up-or-down", component_property="value"),
)
def update_graph(up_or_down):
    if up_or_down == "Up!":
        return px.line(return_data_up(), x="x", y="y")
    elif up_or_down == "Down!":
        return px.line(return_data_down(), x="x", y="y")
    else:
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This app has two radio buttons: Up! and Down! When the user changes the selection, the plot updates too.

What I'd like to achieve: when copying the link to Slack, I'd like it to [unfurl](https://medium.com/slack-developer-blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-unfurling-but-were-afraid-to-ask-or-how-to-make-your-e64b4bb9254) based on the content of the page at the moment when the link is copied. For that, I'd need the following `meta` tags in `<head>`:

```html
<head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Dash app: Up!"> <!-- change dynamically -->
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"> <!-- constant -->
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://my-url-does-not-exist-foobar.com"> <!-- constant -->
    <meta property="og:description" content="This is my dash app!"> <!-- constant -->
    <title>my dash app</title> <!-- constant -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
```

Though in the end, I'd like most of those tags to update dynamically, for the sake of the example, I'm happy if only the title changes based on which radio button is selected when the link is copied. I.e.

- when Up! is selected it should be:
  `<meta property="og:title" content="Dash app: Up!">`,
- otherwise: `<meta property="og:title" content="Dash app: Down!">`

What I've tried so far (and I'm not saying these can't work, but I didn't succeed):

1. overriding the `Dash` class to create a custom `interpolate_index` function, i.e.:

```py
class CustomDash(Dash):
    def interpolate_index(self, **kwargs):
        [...]
```

Here, I didn't know how to pass arguments (kwargs) to the function. I was able to add static meta tags. ([source](https://dash.plotly.com/reference#app.interpolate_index))

2. `app = Dash(__name__, meta_tags=meta_tags)`
   Here, I was also only able to add static meta tags but couldn't update them while the app was running ([source](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources#overriding-default-tags))
3. I've added the `html.Meta` component to the `app.layout` and set a callback to change it's content. This threw an error. ([source](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/meta))
   I don't think this can work, based on the docs:

> CAUTION: `<meta>` is included for completeness, but generally will not behave as expected since  tags should be static HTML content in the `<head>` of the document. Dash components are dynamic  content.

What I couldn't implement but could be a way forward:

1. Adding Your Own CSS and JavaScript to Dash Apps ([source](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources#example:-including-local-css-and-javascript))

I'm not sure if this is the right way forward but thought I'd share what I've tried. Any help is appreciated. Many thanks